# ImageView center on top of scrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, imageview, scrollview

Ok so I have two `UIImageViews` which are in the subview of a `UIScrollView`. What I want is that when  the user scrolls somewhere on the screen and clicks on a table(a button on the screen), a popup (UIImageview) comes up. What I want is that the image view be at the **`center`**. Here is my code:

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"%f scrollView Last X", scrollView.contentOffset.x);
    NSLog(@"%f scrollView Last y", scrollView.contentOffset.y);

    //This is for the orders
    self.roundFrame = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190 + scrollView.contentOffset.x ,120 + scrollView.contentOffset.y, 385, 280)];
    self.roundFrame.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_round_edge.png"];
    [_roundFrame setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    //This is for the split Table
    self.roundFrameForSplit = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190 +  scrollView.contentOffset.x, 120 + scrollView.contentOffset.y, 370, 300)]; // 362
    self.roundFrameForSplit.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_round_edge.png"];
    [_roundFrameForSplit setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

What's happening though is that most times it comes in the center, but sometimes it does not come in the center. I do not know how to fix this. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks for the help!

EDIT: For anyone looking for the answer to this question in the future, here it is. Since in my case(your's could be different depending on what you want to accomplish), I just wanted the UIImageView in the center of a ipadMini screen, so I just kinda cheated a bit and hardcoded the values(1024 /2 , and 768 / 2). Don't forget to add your UIImageView as a subview to self.View(I made the mistake and was lost lol). Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make **imageview** outside of the **scrollview** and have it hidden.

When you want it to display over the **scrollview**, give the **imageview** it's image and un-hide it.

Comment: My scrollView is HUGE to allow the user to scroll. I have the imageview on top of it, but whenever the imageview comes up, i gray out the background and disable interaction(i do not let user scroll when image view is there).

Comment: I'm not sure how to use them...Can you give an example please?

Comment: You can either build them in interface builder or programmatically. I suggest starting in IB. The general idea of constraints being you set the distance from a fixed position that can fluctuate depending on the size of the device. I would suggest reading this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/UnderstandingAutolayout.html

Comment: Thanks! But i'm wondering, can I not just get the bounds of the ipad mini screen and divide width/2 and height/2 to center the imageview?

Comment: You can, under the assumption your image will always be the exact same size, you don't have to take rotation into consideration and you don't want to add anything else, like a frame around your picture. All possible, but WAY more work.

Comment: I tried the following:

        CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2;
        CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / 2;
        

But whenever i scroll, the location changes.. I thought the mainscreen was suppose to be static size of actual ipad mini is it not?

Comment: Na, you need to use your top view. Assuming you are using IB.

Comment: I'm not using IB. I tried this:    

 UIWindow *topWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIWindow *win1, UIWindow *win2) {
        return win1.windowLevel - win2.windowLevel;
    }] lastObject];

UIView *topView = [[topWindow subviews] lastObject];

Answer (score 0):

Try To Write same code in

> - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

also and then check.

Comment: Should i keep (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView or remove it and replace it with this function? Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Use both, Because 1 is called when u drag fast and 2nd one is called when u dragging slowly

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this might do it.

Comment: QA testing underway.. will get back to you as soon as it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

It is might be your thread . Do this work on main thread like as

```
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(yourMethos:) withObject:YourObject waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I hope you understand it and can apply easily. Thanks